# Downgrading Docker from 19.03.2 to 18.09.9 on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, docker-ce

I've been trying to downgrade docker from 19.03.2 to 18.09.9 on CentOS 7. I installed it via yum.

This is what I've tried so far.

Only a single version available returned.

```
$ yum list docker-ce.x86_64 --showduplicates | sort -r 
 * updates: centos4.zswap.net
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Installed Packages
 * extras: mirrors.usinternet.com
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 docker-ce.x86_64   3:19.03.2-3.el7 .  @docker-ce-stable
 * base: centos4.zswap.net
```

No luck on this, duh!

```
$ yum downgrade docker-ce.x86_64 3:18.09.9-3.el7
```

Tried to downgrade it with downloaded rpm packages. No luck either.

```
$ yum downgrade file docker-ce-cli-18.09.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm 
$ yum downgrade file docker-ce-18.09.9-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

Finally, the docker engine command ran successfully, but now there are two different versions, APIs are the same though.

```
$ docker engine update --version 18.09.9
```

Two different docker versions.

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.2
 API version:       1.39 (downgraded from 1.40)
 Go version:        go1.12.8
 Git commit:        6a30dfc
 Built:             Thu Aug 29 05:28:55 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
 Version:          18.09.9
 API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:       go1.11.13
 Git commit:       039a7df
 Built:            Wed Sep  4 16:22:32 2019
 OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
 Experimental:     false
```

How do I downgrade the client now?

Comment: yum remove everything and install it again

Comment: Is there a way just to downgrade the client now?

Answer (score 5):

Let's say if I want to downgrade my own `Client: Docker Engine - Community` from *19.03.2* to **18.09.9**.

And below is the list of available versions.

```
yum list docker-ce-cli --showduplicates | sort -r

docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.7-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.6-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.5-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.4-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.3-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.2-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.1-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:19.03.0-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.9-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.8-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.7-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.6-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.5-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.4-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.3-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.2-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.1-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.0-3.el7              docker-ce-stable 
docker-ce-cli.x86_64              1:18.09.0-3.el7              @docker-ce-stable
```

I can achieve this by executing the following command.

`for i in {1..3}; do yum downgrade docker-ce-cli -y; done`

Comment: Consider also downgrading "docker engine/core". Something like: `yum downgrade docker-ce-20.10.5-3.el7`.

Answer (score -5):

To downgrade your docker-ce version you need to tap this cmd :

```
sudo apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades docker-ce=17.03.2~ce-0~ubuntu-xenial
```

Comment: apt wont work on CentOS. Read the desc carefully.